# android admob google-play-services interstitial video ads and dismissal

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, interstitial

I received a user review that describes "having to sit through a video ad".

I thought all interstitial ads were easy to dismiss via either the device back button or the included [x] button...

Are there video ads that force a user to watch a portion / the whole video before being "dismissable"?

If so, is there a way of preventing such ads from being in the "ad lineup"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never come across an ad that wasn't cancelable.

Answer (score 0):

1-Log in to your AdMob account at https://apps.admob.com.

2-Click the Monetise tab.

3-Click All apps on the left-hand side and select the app that you want to modify.

4-Click + New ad unit.

5-Next select “Interstitial” as the ad Format

6-select Ad type you want to show